# WCF service design dilemma

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I am going to design new WCF service and need advise about the problem I am struggling with. We have a big object which is called Region and Region has many streets, roads. Street and and Roads have some child objects. So, service consumer can ask to

- Create new Region
- Add new street to existing Region
- Add new sub object to existing Street
- Delete street from Region
- ...

So, shall I create single method that takes Region and decide which object needs to be added/updated/deleted behind the method. (I think this is called message based design)?

Or

Shall I create many methods that fulfill each request(that is classic WCF interface)?

Comment: I would go with multiple methods which will give you finer control and exception handling also testability.

Comment: This is a classic example of where a REST interface is simpler and more intuitive than SOAP (WCF DataContract). If you are starting a new service I would suggest checking on WebAPI. Read this example and see if you don't think its more intuitive: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Answer (score 0):

Based on the service scenario you defined, I recommend consideration of WCF Data Services as a mechanism to expose the data via your new service.   The following snippet from MSDN provides additional information:

WCF Data Services enables creation and consumption of data services for the Web or an intranet by using the Open Data Protocol (OData). OData enables you to expose your data as resources that are addressable by URIs. This enables you to access and change data by using the semantics of representational state transfer (REST), specifically the standard HTTP verbs of GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. This topic provides an overview of both the patterns and practices defined by OData and also the facilities provided by WCF Data Services to take advantage of OData in .NET Framework-based applications.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358710(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is called message based design, and I am not a design expert either. But thinking as the client side of your service I would have wanted the classic WCF interface approach. Since there are certain jobs, I would look for methods to do those jobs. Otherwise I  would feel confused for using the same method for every job.

By coding the tasks in seperate methods you will increase maintainability too. Both on client side and service side.